# How to close Settings activity in android Programatically, similar app lock

Tags: java, android, locking, settings

i want make app similar app lock, when I open the settings screen, I need to put a key, if it is correct, I must go, otherwise you close the settings screen.

Thanks!!!

firts steep:
-> open settings screen
next steep:
-> open my lock activity
final steep: 
-> press back button and closing settings screen and return in home screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uli6H.jpg

Sorry for my enlish, i use Google translate :v

Comment: What's your question? We can't just simply write your code for you.

Comment: i'm Sorry, i need code close for the  setting activity. when press back button, in my lockactivity, close the settings screen.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across this problem whilst developing an automated test solution for an Android Application I've been working on. So, if you're in a similar position to me and have access to `UiAutomation` via:

**build.gradle**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

I found that we may programmatically kill the process using a call to the `adb shell`. i.e.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("am force-stop com.android.settings"); }
```

Hope this helps out somebody who finds themselves in a similar position.